# why can't I see xml view in fragment in android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I made a clock setting fragment for an alarmManager. I also specified in navigation, but the views I made do not appear in the clock fragment, I could not figure out why, what is the problem?

**ClockFragment**

```
class ClockFragment : Fragment() {


    private val viewModel:ClockViewModel by viewModels()
    private lateinit var fragmentClockBinding :FragmentClockBinding

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val binding = FragmentClockBinding.bind(view)
        fragmentClockBinding = binding

        
    }




}
```

**fragment_clock.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".presentation.home.setClock.ClockFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"

        >

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/datePicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:datePickerMode="spinner"
            android:calendarViewShown="false"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:layout_margin="6dp"

            />
        <TimePicker
            android:id="@+id/timePicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:timePickerMode="spinner"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"

           />

      

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

**clockFragment image**

[image]

**HomeFragment**

When the clock icon is clicked on the HomeFragment, the setClock function works to go to the clockFragment and it goes to the clockFragment, but nothing appears on the screen.

```
override fun setClock() {
        println("setclock Home fragment")
        val action:NavDirections = HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToClockFragment()
        findNavController().navigate(action)
    }
```

**navigation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.enestigli.todoapp.presentation.home.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_addNoteFragment"
            app:destination="@id/addNoteFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_editNoteFragment"
            app:destination="@id/editNoteFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_clockFragment"
            app:destination="@id/clockFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/addNoteFragment"
        android:name="com.enestigli.todoapp.presentation.home.addnote.AddNoteFragment"
        android:label="fragment_add_note"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_add_note" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_addNoteFragment_to_homeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/homeFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/editNoteFragment"
        android:name="com.enestigli.todoapp.presentation.home.editnote.EditNoteFragment"
        android:label="fragment_edit_note"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_edit_note" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_editNoteFragment_to_homeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/homeFragment" />
        <argument
            android:name="currentNote"
            app:argType="com.enestigli.todoapp.room.Note" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/clockFragment"
        android:name="com.enestigli.todoapp.presentation.home.setClock.ClockFragment"
        android:label="fragment_clock"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_clock" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_clockFragment_to_homeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/homeFragment" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

**navigation image**

[image]

**FragmentClock phone image**

Here, the datepicker I made in fragment clock.xml should appear, but a blank screen appears like this.

[image]

**UPDATE**

I found the cause of the problem. It's happening for a reason that I completely overlooked. I'm developing the project using hilt and I forgot to add @AndroidEntryPoint to the fragment, also I didn't give the fragment in the fragment constructer. Here is the solution to the problem

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ClockFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_clock)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not inflating the fragment_clock.xml at *runtime*. The preview is visible as you have set the `tools:layout` attribute.

Documentation for inflating viewbinding to fragment
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#fragments